# Coequalizer in the category of modules

Tags: category-theory, modules, equivalence-relations, limits-colimits

I am trying to prove that the category of modules is cocomplete. It suffices to show that it has all coequalizers and coproducts. It's relatively easy to show that all coproducts exist, and I am left to prove that all coequalizers exist in the category of modules. Thus, let $f, g : M \to N$ be $R$-module homomorphisms where $M$ and $N$ are $R$-modules. I am guessing that the coequalizer must be $N / \sim$, where $\sim$ is an equivalence relation of some sort. However, if we simply defined $\sim$ as the smallest equivalence relation on $N$ such that $f(n) \sim g(n)$ for all $n \in N$, I don't know how to show that the $R$-module structure on $N / \sim$ defined as $r \cdot [n] := [rn]$ is well defined. I am thinking that perhaps the $\sim$ should be defined slightly differently, in which case I would need to prove the universal property. However, I am not sure how. Can you help?

Comment: To prove that coequalizers exist it's enough to compute cokernels, i.e. coequalizers of $f$ and a zero map; this because then the coequalizer of $f,g$ is $\text{coker} (g-f)$. This said, on coker(f) you define the module structure precisely that way!

Answer (score 0):

The relation $\sim$ should be defined as $f(m) \sim g(m)$ for all $m \in M$. This means that $\sim$ generates the submodule $N' = \{f(m)-g(m) | m\in M\}$.

To prove that the $R$-module structure on $N/\sim$ is well defined, $\forall n \in N$, $m \in M$, $r \in R$,
$$
r(n + f(m) - g(m)) = rn + f(rm) - g(rm)
$$
So $r(n + f(m) - g(m)) - rn$ is in the submodule $N'$.

Comment: thanks so much. I am still unsure how this proves that the module structure is well defined, as $\sim$ is *generated* by $f(m) - g(m)$. What if we have two elements $n', n$ in the same equivalence class but their difference $n' - n$ is some element that is not of the form $f(m) - g(m)$?

Comment: Instead of showing that the structure is well defined, it is sufficient to see that $N'$ is a submodule of $N$, which is very easy. Then you have $N/\sim=N/N'$, which has a canonical $R$-module structure

Comment: @Squirrel-Power. Do you know that the definition of $N/\sim$ is exactly $N/N'$?